# Connection attributes in firebase query React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I would like to get books from Firebase where author or title is given with React. Sth like that :

```
fire.firestore().collection('books').where('name OR author', '==', elFromMyState).
        get().
        then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                let element = doc.data();
                array.push(element)
            })
            setBooks(array);
            props.setList(array);
        })
```

but don't know how to do it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, firebase provides limited support for logical OR queries.

You can specify multiple value comparisons (logical OR's) for the **same** field. For example, looking for either `Poland` `OR` `Austria` in a `neighboringCountries` field.

You cannot specify multiple fields against which you query a single value. For example, looking for the value `Nikola Tesla` on fields `people` `OR` `inventors`.

The limitations are explained in more detail in the firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations

They explain that in order to work around this, you execute two independent queries, then combine the results on the front end for display.